# Table doesn't exist in engine

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin

I installed xampp but when i am trying to open databases in phpmyadmin, i get an error.

***#1932 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma__tracking' doesn't exist in engine***

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and no solutions. The dump file embedded with Xampp doesn't works. If you had solved the problem I'm interested !

Answer (score 0):

Try installing an older version of XAMPP. In my case helped change from xampp-linux-x64-5.6.14-4 to xampp-linux-x64-5.6.12-0.